# as3-websocket-server, how to manage the results

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I downloaded the library as3-websocket-server ( https://github.com/childoftv/as3-websocket-server ) for a desktop air app and I'm trying to manage the results.

I'm using Flash professional, so I import the code by:

```
import com.childoftv.websockets.WebSocketServer;
```

Than I'm able to run the server by:

```
var sock:WebSocketServer = new WebSocketServer();
sock.attemptBind(8087,"127.0.0.1");
```

It works fine with an html5 client on any browser (I see it adding some trace in the .as file). But how can I manage the data I get from the browser directly in the main FLA file?

Instructions say to see WebSocketServerBasic.as but it neither works: I get error on invalid number of arguments (max1) calling the function WebSocketServerBasic.

So I'm using the main WebSocketServer.as But I don't find any code to manage the results... I should need something like:

```
sock.onMessageReceived (do something with the message...)
```

or some addEventListener...

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked with WSS, but just looking at it makes it something like that:

```
import com.childoftv.websockets.WebSocketServer;
import com.childoftv.websockets.events.ClientEvent;

var sock:WebSocketServer = new WebSocketServer();
sock.addEventListener(ClientEvent.CLIENT_MESSAGE_EVENT, handleMessage);
sock.attemptBind(8087, "127.0.0.1");

function handleMessage(e:ClientEvent):void
{
    trace(e.msg);
}
```

Comment: Yesss!!! So easy! I looked into events/ServerEvent.as and not in ClientEvent.as as I thought I'm running a server, but correctly the message received is a client event! Thanks a lot!